# Bootloader with mouse support

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mouse, bootloader

Are there any boot loaders which support using a mouse to select the operating system / boot options?

This will not just be a helpful as a convenience feature, but is required for old laptops (like mine) whose arrow keys are bust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gujin

This has worked pretty well for me in the past. The project is currently hosted on SourceForge and you can download the sources / binaries from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gujin

The SourceForge page does not have any information on usage, but there is some good documentation on the OSDev wiki here:

http://wiki.osdev.org/Gujin

If all you're looking for are simple and straightforward instructions for a basic installation, here they are:

1. Firstly, you have to download gujin from it's sourceforge project page.
2. Then, in a terminal issue the following command as root:

   `gujin (or ./gujin) /boot/gujin.ebios`
3. Wait until it finishes, and reboot.
4. Ta-dah! You have now installed gujin. Isn't it better?

Source:
http://linuxlalala.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-install-gujin-bootloader-on-linux.html